# How to initiate the size of form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, forms

If I run my program this is what I see

[image]

That's not the size of the form that I make. It seems that when I click run, windows set the size of the form as the size of any standard form that shows up.

The size of the form is similar to the size of a newly opened internet explorer.

If I set the form to be unresizeable the form is indeed unresizeable but it's initial size is determined by windows.

How do I set that the size of the form match the size of the form when I design the program?

Comment: It seems that my form will open up with that size no matter how I set it up in form designer. I want it to have the size of the form?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check a couple of properties of the form as a combination of these may affect the form size such as `AutoScale`, `AutoSize`, `FormBorderStyle`, `WindowState`. Also check for the `DefaultSize`, `Size`, `Width`, `Height`, `MaximizedBounds` and `ClientSize` properties.

You should also check the form events, particularly `Load` event, whether you are setting any of those properties in these events?

As another approach you can try fixing the form size in the `Load` event.

Comment: everything is in order. It seems that the form is resized sometimes after it's loaded automatically by windows. I will just look at resize events.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you are using WinForms, try setting the form's StartPosition property to WindowsDefaultLocation, CenterScreen or Manual.